# Photoshop and CSS3 background shadow

Tags: html, css, photoshop

There is a regular psd file only with the background.

I have Photoshop CS 5.1, ran into a problem: I do not know how to cut out the background or the background to be two main background was such a stretch greens here at 100%, while the other (which is at the center of the white glow) was like in the center of the future site. I was just trying not to cut. Either cut out the curve, or the background is not inserted.

In short it is necessary that the central part of the site was a white shadow:)

Sorry for bad english

Comment: Do you have your psd set up with different layers?

Comment: Ok, explain what you're trying to do again? I'm not following which part of your psd you're having trouble extracting.

Comment: I'm trying to make the center of the site was a round white shadow with height 500 pixels

Comment: So you just want the round white shadow and not the green part? If so, can you just turn off the layers that aren't the white shadow and save for web from there (most likely as a .png to preserve transparency?)

Comment: The fact that after this sharp transition is obtained by the background, and I want to smooth. http://imwox.com/view/4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6250/discussion-between-isis-and-kinakuta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that it's not a good idea to use a software who is designed for digital photograph post-production, when you are trying  to illustrate something. I strongly recommend Illustrator or Inkscape instead of photoshop wich I think is great for other purposes.

This article could be useful to achive the gradien to transparent effect in illustrator.

http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/transparent-gradients-in-illustrator/

Are you trying to do something like what I sketched out in this fiddle?:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vvz3/

If not, let me know where's the diference and mayebe I could help you out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to cut out the background. Instead use the entire image as a large background for your site. Here is an article that explains how to use a large background. Hope this helps.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/how-to-css-large-background